# mapbox.js: set map limit bounds

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm working on a map with mapbox.js but I want to set a limit to map bounds and zoom.
What code I've to add to this script?

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y').setView([40, -74.50], 9);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are options you can put in an object to pass to `L.mapbox.map` as the third argument. The [documentation for `L.mapbox.map`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-mapbox-map/) says that is can take all the same options as Leaflet's `L.map`, which are [documented here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-map-class/). The options you want are `minZoom`, `maxZoom`, and `maxBounds`. Eg:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y', {
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 12,
        maxBounds: [[30.0,-85.0],[50.0,-65.0]]
    }).setView([40, -74.50], 9);
```